# How do I use Openstack Cinder volumes as Kubernetes persistant volume?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, openstack

I have kuberentes running in Openstack, and I want to use volumes provided by openstack rather than using NFS to manage volumes. I'm not sure where to start or if its even possible. i've tried bunch of stuff, no luck :(

Here is some methods I've tried so far. 
I modified the /etc/kubernetes/manifests/kube-conroller yaml file. I mounted the cloud.conf file and added these lines

```
- --cloud-provider=openstack
- --cloud-config=/etc/kubernetes/cloud.conf
```

Then I ran this to create my storage class

```
apiVersion: storage.k8s.io/v1
kind: StorageClass
metadata:
  name: openstack-test
  annotations:
    storageclass.beta.kubernetes.io/is-default-class: "true"
  namespace: mongo-dump
  labels:
    kubernetes.io/cluster-service: "true"
    addonmanager.kubernetes.io/mode: EnsureExists
provisioner: kubernetes.io/cinder
parameters:
  type: fast
  availability: nova
```

Then created my pvc

```
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: cinder-claim
  annotations:
    volume.beta.kubernetes.io/storage-class: "standard"
spec:
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 1Gi
```

After this step its just stuck at pending. :9

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. You should probably use another site on the [Stack Exchange network](https://stackexchange.com/sites) for this question. Also see [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center.

Comment: What kubernetes version you are using, and where it's hosted?

Comment: kubectl version:   $ kubectl version
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"15", GitVersion:"v1.15.0", GitCommit:"e8462b5b5dc2584fdcd18e6bcfe9f1e4d970a529", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2019-06-19T16:40:16Z", GoVersion:"go1.12.5", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"14", GitVersion:"v1.14.6", GitCommit:"96fac5cd13a5dc064f7d9f4f23030a6aeface6cc", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2019-08-19T11:05:16Z", GoVersion:"go1.12.9", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}

Comment: My kubernetes cluster is hosted on top of openstack